# Warning 1946 during upgrade

Tags: windows-installer, warnings

Then started to use ExcludeFromShowInNewInstall flag in msi, we faced the rare and hard to reproduce warning 1946 on update.

> MSI (s) (8C:78) [14:17:27:198]: Executing op: ShortcutPropertyCreate(ShortcutName=CHECK_~1|Check for updates,PropertyKey={9F4C2855-9F79-4B39-A8D0-E1D42DE1D5F3}, 8,PropVariantValue=1)
>   MSI (s) (8C:78) [14:17:27:198]: Note: 1: 1946 2: {9F4C2855-9F79-4B39-A8D0-E1D42DE1D5F3}, 8 3: Check for updates.lnk 4: 32 
>   MSI (s) (8C:78) [14:17:27:198]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038

The same issue as described here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/543254/silverlight-rc-will-not-install-due-to-error-messages-system-appusermodel-excludefromshowinnewinstall
and here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/1c1e9a8c-f838-42b9-95a1-6b11060c588b

they suggested this solution:

> attrib -a *.lnk

but this is customer-side solution but not developer side.

It seems Microsoft have kind of bug in their msiexec as their own piece of software faced the same issues. But and no solid solution or explanations found.

There is KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2745126 but that is unrelated issue.

Has anyone faced the same issue? How to avoid or workaround it?

Comment: another case http://communities.vmware.com/thread/390879

Comment: and another one http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/240/

Comment: The following links shed light on the issue, which is apparently a Windows Installer issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows/win32/warning-1946-when-you-install-installer-package

and 

https://community.flexera.com/t5/InstallShield-Forum/Warning-1946-Property-9F4C2855-9F79-4B39-A8D0-E1D42DE1D5F3-12/td-p/45966